Can you have bidirectional correlation in path analysis?
Something like this:
Where B causes A, C causes D, and A and D are directly correlated.
Is it possible to solve a system like this?


Yes, that's possible to solve.  It's a pretty standard model.
It assumes that the regression of D on B controlling for C is zero, and the effect of A on C controlling for B is also zero. The model will have 2 degrees of freedom (because of those two missing paths). If you add in those two paths, it's just-identified and will give the same result as a multivariate regression.
(Your use of $\beta$ and $\theta$ are not conventional and might confuse people.)
Edit: If I were fitting this model in lavaan, I would use:
A ~ B
D ~ C
A ~~ D
B ~~ C


Yes, I am certain that A-C paths and B-D paths are not possible. Could you please expand a bit on how the system of equations would look like?

Maybe I've misunderstood, or we are talking about different things? I would use lavaan and the code would look like:
A ~ B
D ~ C
A ~~ D
B ~~ C
This model would have 2 df.
(Oh, sorry, text formatting isn't working, I'll edit the question).

This bidirectional correlation is common in path analysis but is often used for exogeneous variables only by curved bidirectional arrows (such as the path denoted by your hypothesized $\beta$), not in your case between endogenous A and D where you can only enforce bidirectional mutual causal path by two separate straight arrows usually.
To solve the system with all the raw correlation between any two variables you just need to add the contributions from all compound paths between them, and the compound path criterion follows Wright’s path tracing rules. For example, $r_{BD}=\beta \alpha + \gamma \theta, r_{AD}=\theta + \gamma \beta \alpha$, etc, assuming you have the hypothesized bidirectional correlation between exogenous B and C.

Would you mind explaining this a bit more? How would the system of equations look like?

@Caterina I added two non-trivial raw correlation equations from path analysis per your request, you could fit your path model to any pair of variables similarly. Hope this clarifies.

In those path tracing rules it says "No more than one bi-directional arrow can be included in each path-chain", does my diagram fulfill this? Just in case,  is not an actual correlation, is just something I measure (but there is no true correlation). What I'm trying to understand is whether  can be explained by . Also BD and AC paths don't exist.

@Caterina Your diagram even adding bidirectional correlation curved arrows between exogenous B and C is perfectly ok (and you only have one such curved arrows here anyway) as implied in my above answer, in fact by including it your diagram becomes complete. But per the path tracing rules, you cannot have $$ as one compound path from B to C, since you have to go backward after going forward, you cannot avoid this. So the raw correlation between B and C, if it exists as non-zero, is just your hypothesized $$. Hope this further clarifies.
